# Javascript Approved Number in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to change a value user enters to a true number (ex. 15 or 144.38). If it has unapproved characters (ex. $,) then they should be stripped. Also if user enters value with multiple periods (ex. 43.14.14) then I want to clear entire value. I was able to do step 1 but can't figure step 2, please advise. Here's my code so far
http://jsbin.com/otawiVa/1

```
function myFunction()
{
  var str = document.getElementById("number_field").value;
  var res = str.replace(/[^0-9.}]/g,"");
  document.getElementById("approved_number").innerHTML=res;
}
```

Comment: For, the latter, you *could* just do `if (res.indexOf('.') !== res.lastIndexOf('.')) document.getElementById("number_field").value = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function to

```
function myFunction()
{
var str = document.getElementById("number_field").value;
var res = str.replace(/[^0-9.}]/g,"");
  if (res.indexOf('.') !== res.lastIndexOf('.')) {
    document.getElementById("approved_number").innerHTML="";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("approved_number").innerHTML=res;
  }
}
```

Example here:

http://jsbin.com/UNOHoYek/1

Comment: This works well. I was just hoping maybe its possible to avoid the conditional statement and check for no more than one period inside regular expression pattern

Comment: 15e3 -> 153
15.000,00 -> 15.00000

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsbin.com/OKoJuloQ/3/ for a possible answer.

Changing user input without providing feedback is probably not a good idea.

Better to just handle what can be taken as a number and report the rest.

window.alert is just one way to report it.

The important bits are the conversion to `Number` and testing against `NaN`.

**CODE** (also available via link above)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" id="number_field">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="approved_number"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    try {
      var str = document.getElementById("number_field").value;
      // var res = str.replace(/[^0-9.}]/g,"");
      var res = str;
      if (Number.isNaN(Number(res))) {
        window.alert(res + " is not a number (NaN)\nOnly digits, decimal point,\nand exponent (e.g. 3.2e4) are allowed");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("approved_number").innerHTML=Number(res).toString(10);
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      window.alert(exception);
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The exception handling is not needed at this point, but might be useful in case you get adventurous with further code changes.

Comment: I have a requirement for my code to not produce any alerts. So if a user enters $15,144 - the app should just output a cleaned up value 15144

Comment: Yeah, the alert was just an example.
That's a comma in $15,144. You are not concerned about internationalization then? comma would be used as decimal point in German, where your use of the throusand mark would be a period in German (€15.144,00).
I guess the exponent handling is not needed, but what if someone
entered 1.5e4, that would just become 1.54 (shudder).